# Why is the bootstrap carousel component not working properly in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, bootstrap-5

I created a new  fragment, and in it, I copy-pasted the standard Bootstrap carousel component code, both css and javascript. The CSS works well, and the fragment looks like the normal carousel, but when I click on a slide, there is a blank white page between each slide. I tried using the CDN link instead, and it's the same.

Here's my code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide pointer-event" data-bs-ride="true">
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2" class=""></button>
        <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3" class="active" aria-current="true"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: First slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#555" dy=".3em">First slide</text></svg>
    
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Second slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#666"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#444" dy=".3em">Second slide</text></svg>
    
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg d-block w-100" width="800" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: Third slide" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#555"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#333" dy=".3em">Third slide</text></svg>
    
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

And this is what I am seeing:
[image: First slide]

[image: When I click second slide, a blank white page slides in first]

[image: Then the normal 2nd slide appears after the blank one]

This doesn't happen on any other working environment, so therefore it must be a Liferay issue.

I am inserting the custom fragment inside a page, and then just 'viewing' it.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you notice that liferay already include bootstrap framework? 

Maybe the bootstrap@5.2.2 breaks the page env.

Comment: Yeah, that's one possibility. So, what do you suggest I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, Liferay 7.4 includes Bootstrap 4. You're pulling in your own carousel and I'm quite certain that this mismatch causes issues.

Comment: I see. So, what do you suggest I do?

Comment: Better learn css

Comment: Use bootstrap4's carousel (from the same version that Liferay includes, maybe the code is even already there? (I haven't tried that)). Or use a different, non-bootstrap carousel. Or bring your own matching JS/CSS

Comment: So, I used the Bootstrap 4 component inside Liferay without any JS, and there is no functionality at all. So, first of all, why? If Liferay uses imbedded Bootstrap, why is there no JS bootstrap applied to the fragments? Also, I copied the CDN JS link inside the fragment, and the sliding worked, but it had the exact same issue! There's again this blank page in between slides.

Comment: Any ideas where does this come from?

Comment: I'm not a good frontend reference, but it might include Bootstrap CSS, not JS, so if you bring in JS: Make sure it's from BS4, and ideally matching the CSS Liferay brings.

Comment: I did use the BS4 Javascript.

Comment: Do you think there's a way to disable or overwrite liferay's bootstrap?

Comment: No. But please keep in mind: If you have already added a fragment to the page, then any change to the "templated" fragment that you used to add it to the page does not immediately reflect on the page. You can check its usage and propagate it to all pages, or remove and add it again to a page.

Comment: @OlafKock I'm not sure what you mean by 'templated' fragment. I am first creating a fragment set, and then copying inside an html fragment, and then inside, I paste the html + JS, the CSS is set globally in `_customs.scss` file. However, I did notice that in the `dropdown` fragment, Liferay overwrites some of the styles that apply to it from the global CSS, and I can overwrite them back by using `!important`. I am guessing something similar is happening with `carousel`, but I can't figure out what style is being overwritten. I don't think this is a JS issue anymore. It's a styles issue I think

Comment: @OlafKock However, I am also wondering if this is even the rich approach. Should I go about finding which styles are overwritten, and then individually overwriting them back with `!important`? I feel like this isn't the rich approach, but I don't know what else to do. Do you have any ideas on how to fix this issue? I have a bunch of components made with customized Bootstrap that I need to find a way to use inside Liferay. I've already found a way to import the compiled CSS on a global level, but even if I find a way to import JS on a global level, I don't know what to do about...

Comment: @OlafKock ... about Liferay overwriting the CSS. Is there a way to stop Liferay from overwriting the global CSS? If I do that, do you think that would solve the issue? Because I don't think going after each individual fragment and finding which individual styles are being overwritten, and then overwriting them back with `!important` is the right approach. I think I need to stop Liferay from overwriting them on a global level. What do you think?

Comment: Those questions go far beyond the original question of why a specific bootstrap 5 component doesn't work on bootstrap 4. "templated" means: as soon as you add the fragment to the page, no edit to the original HTML etc get reflected _on that page_